# want to find number with the most prime divisors but it keeps printing the last inputed number and its divisors

Tags: python, list, python-3.6, primes

the objective is to count prime divisors of three number and print the number with the most prime divisors and its number of prime divisors but my code keeps printing the third number and its number of divisors even though its not the one with the most prime divisors, what should i do?

```
l = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    x = int(input())
    l.append(x)
def prime_counter(n):
    b = 1
    l1 = []
    while b <= n:
        k = 0
        if n % b == 0:
            j = 1
            while j <= b:
                if b % j == 0:
                    k = k + 1
                j = j + 1
            if k == 2:
                l1.append(b)
        b = b + 1
    return l1
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    l2 = []
    if len(prime_counter(l[i])) > len(l2):
        l2 = prime_counter(l[i])

print(l[i], len(l2))
```

Comment: You define `l2` as a blank list (len==0) each time your loop runs, so every element in `l1` will be longer than it, so it will give you the last run result

Answer (score 1):

First of all you could simplify your `prime_counter()` number by removing a for loop :

```
def prime_counter(n):
    l1 = []
    for b in range(1,n+1):
        if n % b == 0:
            l1.append(b)
    return l1
```

Next, you could use a list comprehension to compute the number of prime numbers faster :

```
import numpy as np

l = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    x = int(input())
    l.append(x)

# We save the number of divisors for each number of l    
number_prime_divisor = [len(prime_counter(x)) for x in l]

# Now we just have to look the index with the max number of prime divisors
# using np.argmax
l[np.argmax(number_prime_divisor)]
```

---

With a simple example :

```
l = [4,5,6]

number_prime_divisor = [len(prime_counter(x)) for x in l]
print(number_prime_divisor)
[3, 2, 4]

print(l[np.argmax(number_prime_divisor)])
6
```

Answer (score 0):

On this part of the code you are overwritting l2 with [ ] before every comparation:

```
for i in range(0, len(l)):
  l2 = []
  if len(prime_counter(l[i])) > len(l2):
      l2 = prime_counter(l[i])
```

So:

```
len(prime_counter(l[i])) > len(l2)
```

will be True, as long as prime_counter returns a list with one or more elements, because l2 is empty

To fix this initialize l2 before the for-loop, and store i on a auxiliar variable

```
l2 = []
max_pos = 0
for i in range(0, len(l)):
  if len(prime_counter(l[i])) > len(l2):
      l2 = prime_counter(l[i])
      max_pos = i
print(l[max_pos], len(l2))
```

Comment: I tried writing l2 = [ ] outside the for loop but it still gives me the last number and its divisors

Comment: I forgot to mention, you should also change the last line, you want to print the elements in l2, right? print(l[i], len(l2)) should be print(l2, len(l2))

Comment: I want to print the number with the most prime divisors and the number of its prime divisors for example 6, 2. print(l2, len(l2)) will print something else

Comment: O, I see you should store the index i on a variable to print it, I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your logic here and improve performance by implementing a recursive function:

```
def prime_counter(n, pd, out):

    quot = n/pd

    if quot==1:
        out.append(pd)
        return out
    if int(quot)==quot:
        out.append(pd)
        return prime_counter(quot, 2, out)
    else:
        return prime_counter(n, pd+1, out)

numbers = [12,25,100]

test = {n: prime_counter(n, 2, []) for n in numbers}
```

Yields:

```
{12: [2, 2, 3], 25: [5, 5], 100: [2, 2, 5, 5]}
```

Then it's simple to determine the number with the greatest number of prime divisors, as well as the number of prime divisors (you will want to clarify how you go about breaking ties):

```
most_primes = max(test, key=lambda x: len(test[x]))
number_of_primes = len(test[most_primes])
```

Gives:

```
100
4
```